# sqlite 3.5.9 problem

Tags: android, sqlite

I have query

```
SELECT c.*, sum(cnt.count) AS Questions FROM chapters c 
JOIN( SELECT q.chapterid, count(q.chapterid) AS count, t.LinkChapter 
FROM questions q 
JOIN( SELECT DISTINCT questionid, LinkChapter FROM questionstests 
WHERE testid = '"+ testID +"' )t ON t.questionid = q.questionid 
GROUP BY q.chapterid,t.LinkChapter )cnt 
ON cnt.chapterid = c.chapterid OR cnt.LinkChapter = c.ChapterID 
GROUP BY c.ChapterID ORDER BY SortBy
```

that perfectly worked on sqlite 3.6.22 but throw 'Could not build iterator' exception on sqlite 3.5.9. Can anyone help me with this problem?